# How do I properly migrate from has_secure_password to encrypted_password (as both use password_digest) without losing old passwords?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Migrating from `has_secure_password` to devise causes the following error in the console when interacting with user objects:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/devise-4.4.0/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb:166:in `password_digest'
```

I understand this is because devise uses the `pasword_digest` function and so it is incompatible with the `password_digest` column used by `active record`'s `has_secure password`.

A solution is to delete the `password_digest` column from the db but I do not want to loose existing users' passwords.

Should I delete the `encrypted_password` column devise created and then do a migration to rename `password_digest` to `encrypted_password` and then update existing user's passwords or is there a more appropriate solution?

Comment: have you tried the suggested solution?

Answer (score 7):

1> Rename the column `password_digest` to `encrypted_password`.

2> In devise initializer in `config/initializers/devise.rb` set

```
config.stretches = 11 # this is default
```

3> `bcrypt` is the default hashing or encryption algorithm(so no change needed).

See devise config [template](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/f39c6fd92774cb66f96f546d8d5e8281542b4e78/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb).

Answer (score 3):

I haven't done it before. But in my opinion, let's try to backup your database first. Then perform migration to change password_digest to encrypted_password. Don't worry because you can rollback your migration if it's not worked

Answer (score 2):

Your guess and Sachin's solution are correct. Rename `password_digest` to `encrypted_password` and it will work.

You don't have to change `config.stretches` for this. It only affects how `devise` generates new passwords. Existing password store their number of stretches in their hash.